# Running method at a specific time

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm doing an application in Windows Forms (C#) and I want to set in the Layout an area where the user defines a given hour.

Then, when the user hit the "Start" button, every given hour a method is executed.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: A timer is the easiest way.

Comment: Depends if you can keep the program running for more than 24 hours.  Tends to be the hangup with a class library that's meant to create interactive programs instead of, say, a service.

Comment: Timer Control will greatly help, and if you want to see what method is being executed every hour, you can use Reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple WinForms Timer can get the job done:

```
DateTime runTime;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
  runTime = new DateTime(nowTime.Year, nowTime.Month, nowTime.Day, 12, 0, 0);
  timer1.Interval = 500;
}

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (DateTime.Now > runTime) {
    timer1.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show("It's time!");
  }
}

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  timer1.Start();
}
```

Simply update the runTime value with the hour and/or minute.  The alarm will obviously not get triggered unless the program is running.  As Hans noted, that would require a service.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but something like this?

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer((DateTime.Now - (DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromHours(DateTime.Now.Hour + 1))).Milliseconds);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, evt) =>
{
    timer.Interval = (DateTime.Now - (DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromHours(DateTime.Now.Hour + 1))).Milliseconds;
    // Do things
};
timer.Start();
```